# Is backpressure only needed when the system cannot scale?

Tags: architecture, reactive-programming, autoscaling, backpressure

I was wondering if using backpressure in a system generally did not provide a benefit as it just leads to higher latency / less throughput because it prevents scaling out the overwhelmed resources. Should it only be used for resources that cannot be scaled e.g. a browser client?